# What do the dots in this tr command do: tr .............A-Z A-ZA-Z <<< "JVPQBOV" (with 13 dots)

Tags: tr

I want to use `tr` to do some rot13 transformation. I can beautifully understand this command:

```
tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m <<< "URYC ZR CYRNFR"
```

which output is `HELP ME PLEASE`, but I can't figure out how this other command can produce the same rot13 transformation:

```
tr .............A-Z A-ZA-Z <<< "URYC ZR CYRNFR"
```

So I have two questions:

1. What's the magic behind the second `tr` command?
2. How to make the second command work for both lower and upper case, just like the first command?

Comment: I know there's 13 dots. What I wanna know is how it works. There's no explanation about dots in the manual

Comment: you had better hope you don't run into a dot in your input text

Comment: FWIW the shorter form `tr [.*13].A-Z A-ZA-Z` works just as well as `tr .............A-Z A-ZA-Z`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It works as follows:

```
SET1-> .............ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
SET2-> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

So `tr` will translate `SET1` to `SET2`.

This is equivalent to first one because it is also shifting by `13` units as there 13 dots.

To include the lower case letters, you'll have to arrange them in `SET1` with a similar offset, i.e.:

```
.............ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ..........................abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
```

That's 26 dots between `Z` and `a`, spanning half the upper-case and half the lower-case alphabet. So the `tr` command itself will be:

```
tr .............A-Z..........................a-z A-ZA-Za-za-z
```

Answer (score 14):

As @Prvt_Yadv says in their answer, it works because there are 13 dots.

The sets are

```
First set:  .............ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Second set: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

The dot isn't a special character, so if you have a dot in your input, it will be translated too.  In the version of `tr` that I have, it is the last corresponding character in the second set, in this case an `M`:

```
$ echo URYC ZR CYRNFR. | tr .............A-Z A-ZA-Z
HELP ME PLEASEM
```

(I could imagine that a different version of `tr` might use the first matching character in set 2, which would give an `A`.)

**To answer your second question**, you need another 13 dots in the first set to "use up" the remaining uppercase letters in set 2:

```
First set:  .............ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.............
Second set: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

then you can repeat the pattern:

```
First set:  .............ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ..........................abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Second set: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

which gives us:

```
tr .............A-Z..........................a-z A-ZA-Za-za-z
```

And so:

```
$ echo Uryc zr cyrnfr | tr .............A-Z..........................a-z A-ZA-Za-za-z
Help me please
```

Personally, I think the first way of doing it in your question is simpler!

The first way also doesn't transform any other characters in the input.  For example, compare:

```
$ echo Uryc zr cyrnfr. | tr .............A-Z..........................a-z A-ZA-Za-za-z  
Help me pleasem
```

with

```
$ echo Uryc zr cyrnfr. | tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m
Help me please.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so thanks to @Prvt_Yadv I was able to understand the dots. Here's the first question answer:

> What's the magic behind the second `tr` command?

The 13 dots are simply being mapped to the first 13 letters from the second set. So

`tr .............A-Z A-ZA-Z` will produce the following sets:

```
SET1 -> .............ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
SET2 -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
```

If your input doesn't contain a dot, you can discard the initial sequence, since you won't use those substitution. Then the sets would become:

```
SET1 -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
SET2 -> NOPQRSTUVXWYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
```

But since the first set already contains all 26 letters and set2 has repeating trailing letter, those are discarded too, finally becoming

```
SET1 -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
SET2 -> NOPQRSTUVXWYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

Which is the rot13 substitution and identical to the first command (except for not dealing with lower cases here). The same logic can be applied for the title of the question:

`tr ...A-Z A-ZA-Z <<< “JVPQBOV”` would produce the sets:

```
SET1 -> ...ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
SET2 -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
```

Discarding the initial sequence and the trailing repeating letters they become:

```
SET1 -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ
SET2 -> DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZABC
```

Which is the rot3 substitution.

Now for the second question:

> How to make the second command work for both lower and upper case, just like the first command?

To make it work you put the desired number of dots at the beginning, matching your rot and 26 dots between to upper sequence and the lower sequence, just like this:

```
tr ........A-Z..........................a-z A-ZA-Za-za-z
```

This would successfully create an insensitive rot8. To visualize why this works let's see the sets:

```
SET1 -> ........ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ..........................abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz
SET2 -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz
```

Excluding the dots mapping and trailing letters:

```
SET1 -> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz
SET2 -> IJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZABCDEFGHijklmnopqrstuvxwyzabcdefgh
```

Now it works for both upper and lower case :)

Another way to make it works is to use two `tr` commands as follow:

```
tr .............A-Z A-ZA-Z <<< "ABJ V hqrefgnaq" | tr .............a-z a-za-z
```

A caveat to using the dots substitution was gave by @iruvar: this command will not work as expected when the input string has dots. This is because the dots are being mapped to other letters and when doing the substitution, `tr` will change the input dot to the last mapped letter. But you can actually use any other character than dots. So, if using dots in your `tr` command is a problem, you can use `@` instead, for example. This would work just as fine:

```
tr @@@@@@@@@@@@@A-Z A-ZA-Z <<< "GUNAX LBH NYY..."
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you concluded that "dots are replaced by a sequence of letters starting from a to the number of dots"; that's not at all the case. There's no magic involved; as Prvt_Yadv explained, there are two sets and `tr` is mapping from set 1 to set 2, as always, but in this case you've mapped the character `.` to `A`, and also `B`, and also ..., and also `M`. This doesn't matter since your input doesn't contain a `.`, but if it did it would turn into an `M` (`tr` uses the last output you specify for a given input)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer to fix my mistakes :)

Comment: I admire your (initial) attempts to use science to determine the behaviour of this program, but in future you should come up with as many different hypotheses as possible and design tests to distinguish between all of them _before_ trying to use them. Otherwise you end up getting confused, and adapting your model in a least-changes manner to explain subsequent results until your model's just a mass of special-cases.